# Why would firefox not display images within a local file?

Tags: firefox

I recently sent someone some documentation in HTML format; there's only one page, a css file, and an image.  The image is linked in conventionally:

```
<img src="whatever.png">
```

Where `whatever.png` is in the same directory as the HTML file.  *Note this is **not** a question about coding HTML* as I've been working with it for years.  There's nothing wrong with this part.

However, the person I sent it to says the image does not display when he loads the page.  This person is a tech industry engineer, etc., so very computer literate.  I think he's using a browser on a large institutional network, meaning there could be something odd with the configuration.  The browser is FF 33.  I tried the same package with FF 38, no such problem.

**I'm trying to understand how I got egg on my face here.**  Is there some firefox option that could disable the loading of local images?

Comment: Did you send it as a zip or some other package? Could he have only unpacked one file by accident?

Comment: Yeah it was a `.zip`.  I'm presuming a tech industry engineer is not that dunderheaded but...

Comment: @goldilocks, have you tried debugging it with the file recipient ? there could be tons of possibilities and all we would be able to do is guess until you tell us what exactly how and under what circumstances it was blocked or not loaded

Comment: As it was sent as a ZIP, any chance only the HTML file was extracted? (Like by browsing the ZIP archive in Windows Explorer, which if I remember correctly does not really extract the archive, but my memory might be failing me.) So: is the CSS loaded? Can you add links to another HTML file in the same archive and then: can that link be followed?

Comment: @goldilocks The very first step of accessing the file /index.html could be the source of problem as well. Try double click the zipped folder **not extract** and launch index.html. it would not load image

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Yeah, I know it is awkward without being able to discuss it much with the other party...I can't stand people who ask questions like this ;)

Comment: Anyway, I tried that thing with windows explorer browsing a zip archive and that I have to presume that is the problem -- if you or @Arjan want to jot it down, I'd be happy to give it a tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of possibilities**

1. This is the very first thing where a user could go wrong by **not extracting the .zip file** you sent & **accessing index.html directly** from .zip file preview**.

   *As while previewing zipped files, the file is temporarily extracted to temporary location & it would fail to load the resource as it has not been extracted, even temporarily.*
2. Zipped file not being extracted properly by either user or zip client
3. Firefox related issues like add-ons or other corruption
4. Local policies where the user is accessing the files

   There could be multiple other reasons that might be causing the issue.

If you can contact the user & narrow down the exact situation, Super User would glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It may be for security reasons, so that someone couldn't link to a person's private photos. Try hosting the image on a server, and it would most likely work.

According to: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work , "The ability to open local file links using the methods listed in this article has been removed in Firefox 29 ".

Also, it says that you can use an extension to allow links to local pages.

> Using an Extension:
>
> LocalLink
>
> The LocalLink extension allows overriding the security check per click: links to local pages can be followed using the context menu for the link.

Below stuff was taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391723/how-to-display-local-images-placed-on-client-machine-in-html-webpages

> Use the File API which works on all browsers except IE.
>
> A simple example of this would be:
>
> function ShowImage(filepath){
>
> ```
>    var reader=new FileReader(); // File API object
>
>    reader.onload=function(event){
>
>        document.getElementById('myimage').src = event.target.result;
>
>    }
>
>    reader.readAsDataURL(filepath);
>
>    }
> ```

Comment: @goldilocks I'm adding that right now

Comment: That stuff about local links pertains to stuff where someone does this: `href="file://on/your/computer"`.   But that's not the same thing; as noted in the question, it works fine for me on stock FF, and I've *never* seen a browser where it wouldn't.  It's not a `file://` URL, it's a relative path, i.e., it would only work for local files if it is actually in a local file.  If you ever use local HTML docs, etc. they depend on this functionality.

Comment: It was fixed in FF 30

Comment: From the page you linked: *"For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) **from remote files**..."*.  But the HTML page is not remote.   That this would not work is much weirder than that -- like I said, otherwise it would be impossible to make use of *any* HTML documentation on your computer (which is pretty commonplace, many apps, software libraries, etc. use local HTML docs).

Comment: @goldilocks It still counts as a remote file, and if you search, for that same reason, many HTML documentation does not work, unless it is using an embedded browser in the application

Comment: @goldilocks see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391723/how-to-display-local-images-placed-on-client-machine-in-html-webpages

Comment: **That's still all about `file://` URLs.**  I can't believe it would ever have been applied otherwise without a way bigger internet trail, not to mention I've been an FF user since way before v.29, and have literally thousands of pages of local documentation I've been using on a daily basis.  Think: You are creating a simple, static HTML page on your local system (e.g., using a WYSIWYG editor), but there is no way for you to view the product properly without starting a web server??  I've never seen a system like that.